# VLOOKUP with a MINIF statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, min

I am trying return the value in column B based on the MIN IF function below.

```
=MIN(IF($A:$A=$A2,E:E))
```

The formula for the MIN IF is fine. I have tried various functions but VLOOKUP is the closest I have come in order to return the corresponding column to the minimum value calculated. This is the closest I have come:

```
=VLOOKUP(MIN(IF($A:$A=$A2,E:E)),A:N,2,0)
```

To help, the Min function returns the value in E4 (72.8) and and I need to display the value in B4(1-03).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Your `VLOOKUP` won't work because it is trying to find `72.8` in column A, and failing. When the value you are searching for is not in the first column of your table, use `INDEX` and `MATCH` instead:

```
=INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(MIN(IF($A:$A=$A2,E:E)),$E:$E,0))
```

As long as you don't have any duplicate minimum values in column E you'll be fine.

Comment: This formula appears to be only working about half the time. Its returning incorrect values for example. I have 
=INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(MIN(IF($A:$A=$A3,E:E)),$E:$E,0))
 Where A3 = 1-03. The result of this should not be able to equal 1-03 as the combination of 1-03(column A) and 1-03 (column B) does not exist in the table, yet it is returning 1-03? Any thoughts?